# Critical error with .bbl file but no .bbl file was generated through JabRef

Tags: jabref

I've been working on an IEEEtran type document and up until a few days ago it was generating a PDF and citing the sources just fine when run through LaTeX. I've been using JabRef to manage my sources, create in-text citations with \cite{}, and at the end of the LaTeX document create a bibliography using \bibliography{.bib}.

I added some content and now when I try to run the LaTeX document to generate a PDF, I get the error box screenshotted below, which is a critical error due to the system not being able to find the .bbl file in the error. JabRef doesn't generate a .bbl file and I'm unsure why I wasn't getting this error before if it is a critical file for running the LaTeX document.

[image: bbl error]

The error itself in the error log reads:

"Missing $ inserted.      $
|.61"

I've searched my document and there are no lingering "$" signs, and I can't seem to figure out what is causing this error and/or how to resolve it from reviewing other posts.

Comment: Remove all the automatically generated  auxiliary files, leaving only the sources files (.tex, .bib, .png ...). and try again.

Comment: Just tried that. It sort of worked, but now the error is still the "Missing $ inserted" one that just links to a blank line with no "$". Any ideas how to troubleshoot that as well?

Comment: Reduce the .tex and the .bib files removing  *any* content and code irrelevant for the problem (i.e., remove text, packages, references, images, etc. while the problem is still there, and it is still exactly the same problem, not a new one). At some point, deleting something  will remove the problem. Then it should be evident for you what was wrong. Otherwise,  undelete this change and remove as munch as possible of the remaining document, until you have a true **minimal** working tex. and .bib examples.  Finally, edit the question ans show us that minimal files (= a few lines of code) .

Comment: Thanks for the help Fran, I figured out the issue. It was a single source in my .bib file that had a $ in the title. I just added a \ in front of it and it is working fine now. I'm not sure why the error log was sending me to a completely different line but that change seemed to fix the issue.